Getting an UK Visa with Ricevuta
I recently applied for the permesso di soggiorno. I want to apply to an UK visa at Italy. However, I don’t know If I can get an UK visa with the ricevuta.

I had applied for UK visa while in Singapore with Singapore's equivalent of ricevuta (IPA notification). I was granted UK visa without any questions (My application was otherwise strong).
You can try, if you have some urgent travel is needed and can't wait till your resident card arrives. If you can afford to wait, I suggest to wait.
PS: I tried applying Czech republic visa for the same trip. I was asked to wait till I get the resident card.

A residence permit receipt (‘Ricevuta del permesso di soggiorno’) proves you are not irregular in Italy, while waiting for the renewal or conversion or the first release of the residence permit. It is an official and legally recognized document in Italian territory that shows that you have officially applied for a residence permit.
UK Immigration rules paragraph 28 allow visa applications from any country where the applicant is legally present. So yes, you are eligible to apply for a UK visa with the ricevuta. However, IMHO, you should wait until you receive your Italian residence permit before you do so. The permit constitutes stronger proof of intention to leave the UK than just the ricevuta, so by waiting until you receive it you reduce the risk of a refusal.
